# How to limit recursion depth while expanding variable in GNU makefile?

Tags: recursion, makefile, build, gnu-make

I need macro (variable) for GNU makefile, that searches file/directory by given mask at some of toplevel directories. For example, current working directory is /home/sysop/powerup/native/apps/toopl.  Also exists directory /home/sysop/powerup/native/SDK/build. I want to find location of SDK/build directory relative to current one. So, I wrote recursive macros for that:

```
upfind = $(if $(wildcard $(1)),$(1),$(if $(filter $(abspath $(1)),$(abspath ../$(1))),$(error "can't find $(1)"),$(call upfind,../$(1))))
```

And I now can use it in following way:

```
relpath = $(call upfind, ../SDK/build)
```

And this assigns value "../../SDK/build" to relpath variable.

All fine, but I need propagate such macro to multiple makefiles, so I'am looking way to minimize it (upfind macro). I hope, anybody suggests me how to rewrite this macro in more compact way. For example, it's enought to limit recursion at some level, using of $(abspath) macro isn't necessary. But how can I determine recursion level or measure argument ($(1))length?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here, so this probably isn't an answer.

The recursion limit is simple enough.
First, a bit of tidying:

```
assert-root = $(if $(filter $(abspath $1),$(abspath ../$1)),$(error Can't find $1))
upfind = $(if $(wildcard $1),$1,${assert-root}$(call upfind,../$1))
```

(Note how `$assert-root` is not called, it simply inherits the exisiting `$1`.)
Makes it a bit clearer how we can limit recursion depth: just pass an ever-lengthening `$2`.

```
maxup := 3
assert-depth = $(if $(filter ${maxup},$(words $2)),$(error Can't find [$1] within ${maxup} parents))
upfind = $(if $(wildcard $1),$1,${assert-depth}$(call upfind,../$1,_ $2))
```

Do both at the same time if you like

```
upfind = $(if $(wildcard $1),$1,${assert-depth}${assert-root}$(call upfind,../$1,_ $2))
```